# Evaluating function value via locator on contour plot

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I managed to evaluate a function using a locator on a contour plot with the following code:

```
f[x_, y_] := -x + x^2 + 2 y^2
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}],
  Appearance -> Dynamic[f[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]]]
```

which gives this image:

[image: contour plot and locator]

Would any of my colleagues like to suggest a cuter way? Maybe one that shows the locator and puts the function value as a plot label or some such thing? Something cool and easy for students new to *Mathematica* to easily understand?

The purpose of this activity is to help students guess where the maximum and minimum values lie over this region.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example:

```
DynamicModule[{pt}, LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
              ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
                          PlotLabel -> Row[{"Point: ",
                                            Dynamic[Append[pt, f[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]]]}]]]]
```

[image: locator showing coordinates]

Comment: Thanks J.M. My colleague really liked this suggestion. Really helpful.